# PyInstaller 2.1 IOError

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I'm trying to turn my GUI into an executable file using Pyinstaller. The GUI uses vpython, matplotlib and some other standard python libraries, I have checked that I can import all the modules in the command console using python. I'm building using the command,

```
python pyinstaller.py -p C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages GUI.py
```

The program builds, but when I try to run it I get errors that I don't really understand.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\James\Desktop\PyInstaller-2.1\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.
py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\James\Desktop\PyInstaller-2.1\GUI\build\GUI\out00-PYZ.pyz\visua
l", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\James\Desktop\PyInstaller-2.1\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.
py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\James\Desktop\PyInstaller-2.1\GUI\build\GUI\out00-PYZ.pyz\visua
l_common.create_display", line 35, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\James\Desktop\PyInstaller-2.1\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.
py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\James\Desktop\PyInstaller-2.1\GUI\build\GUI\out00-PYZ.pyz\visua
l_common.materials", line 159, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\James\Desktop\PyInstaller-2.1\GUI\build\GUI\out00-PYZ.pyz\visua
l_common.materials", line 129, in loadTGA
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\James\\Desktop\\PYINST
~1.1\\GUI\\dist\\GUI\\visual_common/turbulence3.tga'
swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'wxPlatformInfo *', no destructor fou
nd.
C:\Users\James\Desktop\PyInstaller-2.1\GUI\dist\GUI>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can right click on the command output, highlight with your mouse, and then copy and paste it here; rather than putting this screenshot which is difficult to parse as the output is truncated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this after reading,

http://osdir.com/ml/python-visualpython-user/2009-07/msg00039.html

The tl;dr is that there is some code in materials.py in Vpython which sets the texture path,

```
if hasattr(sys,'frozen') and (sys.frozen=="windows_exe" or sys.frozen=="console_exe"):
    texturePath="visual\\"
else:
    texturePath = os.path.split( __file__ )[0] + "/"
del sys
```

I commented this out and replaced it with a static path. Then I copied the tga files from Vpython into this path. There is probably a more elegant solution but this workaround is fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed like that :

```
#texturePath="visual\\" --> texturePath="visual_common\\"

#texturePath = os.path.split( __file__ )[0] + "/" -->
texturePath="C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\\visual_common\\"
```

Regards